# Command Prompt random pause

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, node.js, mongodb

I am developing a site using Node.js and MongoDB, both of which are run from the Windows Command Prompt. Occasionally one or both of the programs freezes (no output to console, not accepting incoming connections etc.) often within a few seconds of starting up. Typing any key into the console will unfreeze it and it seems to resume where it left off (connections will complete and any output will be printed).

Note: This is not a problem with my program, in no place do I wait for any keyboard input and it seems to occur fairly randomly, not in a fixed place.

Comment: Same problem here. while konzo's answer is correct, I wonder if there are other things that can cause this

Answer (score 3):

Command prompt will freeze if you click on inside the window... It does this to allow you to select text.. If this is the case you will the the title changed to "Select Command prompt when this occurs"

right clicking or typing will resume it